# Object of type is not JSON serializable in Django

Tags: python, json, django, jsonserializer, django-sessions

I have one dictionary type session called 'cart' and it works fine until I add another one integer type session called 'com_order_id' to my django request.session.
The error is >>>
TypeError at
Object of type Product is not JSON serializable.

Here is the sample session value:

```
{'com_order_id': 59, 'cart': {'3': {'quantity': 1, 'product': <Product: Christmas With Prestige>, 'total_price': 30000, 'total_weight': Decimal('2.30')}}}
```

If I remove one of them, it works. However, storing both 'cart' and 'com' values is giving the error.

Comment: You can not store a `Product`. This is a Django model, but sessions are stored as a JSON blob (by default). Since a Django model is not a dictionary, string, int, etc. that thus fails. You can for example store the *primary key*, but not the `Product` itself.

Comment: Hi Willem, I see what you are point out. I stored the Product in session and used and it was working until I add that 'com_order_id' into that session.

Comment: You likely never stored `Product` in the session, not that if you edit the JSON multiple layers deep, then the update will not "ripple", and hence Django does not know you updated the sessions. Django can only see the "outer shell".

Comment: can you verify that *without* the `com_order_id`, you did save the `Post` object: so that you could retrieve it in another view?

Comment: Yes, I did save it in the cart view. I am using that in my order view to save order items. The json that I provided is from the session value that I got from debugging.

Comment: but this is not JSON, this is a Python dictionary, you can see this by the single quots. The idea is that Django *automatically* will *serialize* it to a JSON blob, and *deserialize* it to Python objects. It is thus not because you print `request.SESSIONS`, that this eventually will get saved, because when you "leave" the view, then serialization takes place. To make matters even worse, if you do not substitute an object, then it is still the same object, so one can not know if you thus altered something *inside* that object.

Comment: yeah serialization problems occurred when leave the view. Strangely, If I don't add 'com_order_id' in the session, it successfully goes to another view. So it is like they both can't work together.